# Post instalation error. Cluster initialization failed

Tags: windows, postgresql, installation

I'm having an issue installing postgresql in my computer:

1. It says "post installation error. Database cluster failed to initialize".
2. Doesn't show the checkbox to start the stack builder.
3. Stack builder wont show the postgresql server.

I really need a hand with this guys, I've tried different solutions:

1. I created a new user with administrator access.
2. Run as administrator.
3. I installed only the server and the postgres command line.
4. I tried to use Xampp and Dbeaver because I use them with Mysql but I can't make them work.

EDIT:

Reading the instalation log it says that bytes secuences for UTF-8 are invalid, but I already have UTF-8 unchecked.

EDIT 2:

I fixed the issue with the UTF-8 now it says

```
Error executing C:\Windows\System32\cscript //NoLogo "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10/installer/server/initcluster.vbs" "NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService" "postgres" "**" "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Temp/postgresql_installer_e722442b0a" "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10" "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\data" 5432 "DEFAULT" 0 : Program ended with an error exit code
Problema al ejecutar el paso post instalación. La instalación no pudo finalizar correctamente
 La inicialización del clúster de la base de datos falló.
Setting variable whoami from C:\Windows\System32\whoami 
Script exit code: 0
```

Comment: Did you use a path or an operating system user name that contain non-ASCII characters?

Comment: how do I check that, my user name is "Usuario", pretty standard.

Comment: Start a command line (`cmd.exe`) and type `whoami`. What is the result you get?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it! Apparently it was due to the use of a utf-8 character in the password